# flutter php file upload file_put_contents($path,base64_encode($file));

Tags: php, flutter, file-upload

I want to upload a file to server when users change there profile
I am using `FilePicker` to pic file and `base64Encode` to get the file Data

```
File? _tempfile;
  String? _fileData;
  String? _fileExe;

  getFile() async {
    FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
      type: FileType.image,
      allowMultiple: false,
    );

    if (result != null) {
      setState(() {
        _tempfile = File(result.files.single.path.toString());
        _fileExe=result.files.single.path.toString().split(".").last;
        _fileData = base64Encode(_tempfile!.readAsBytesSync());
        uploadFile();
        print("file is");
        print(_tempfile);
        print("file ext is");
        print(_fileExe);
        print('file data is');
        print(_fileData);
      });
    } else {
      // User canceled the picker
    }
  }

  uploadFile() async {
    print("uploding");
    var userId =
        await SessionManager().get('user').then((value) => value['user_id']);
    try {
      var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(apiCon.apiEndUserProfile),
          body: {'file': _fileData, 'id': userId,'ext':_fileExe});
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
        if (jsonData['status'] == "error") {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
            content: Text(
              jsonData['message'],
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          ));
        }
        else if(jsonData['status'] == "success" ){
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
            content: Text(
              jsonData['message'],
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          ));
          setState(() {
            count++;
          });
        }
        else{
          print('jsonData');
          print(jsonData);
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

and the php code

I use `base64_encode` to get the file

```
if (isset($_POST['file'])&&isset($_POST['id'])&&isset($_POST['ext'])) {
    $file = $_POST['file'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $ext = $_POST['ext'];
    $temp=time();

    $path="file/profile/$temp$id.$ext";
    
    
    
    $sql="UPDATE `end_user` SET `image`='$path' WHERE `end_user_id`=$id";
    
    file_put_contents($path,base64_encode($file));
    
    try {
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $response['status'] = 'success';
        $response['message'] ='profile update success fully';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $response['status'] = 'error';
        $response['message'] = $e->getMessage();
    }
    
} else {
    $response['status'] = 'error';
    $response['message'] = 'no file found';
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

It will add the data to server and to the data base but the database link is not correct and the file will not open

mysql data `end_user` table image url
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbzJy.png)

server files
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2PuK.png)

when I try to open the file it will be like https://psychologycounseling.000webhostapp.com/file/profile/1682792061163.jpeg

Comment: You are receiving base64 from app side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you already receiving base64 encoded image from app side, you have to decode it first before saving into file.

Replace

`file_put_contents($path,base64_encode($file));`

with

`file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($file));`